# Nested copy/paste loops in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Very new to VBA and trying to write a macro that has a loop within a loop. I'd like the whole code to run 30 times

```
For i = 1 To 30

Worksheets("Salary Extract (SPs Only)").Range("B" & (1 + i)).Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Paste
Destination = Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("B9")

For i = 1 To 9

Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("B" & (38 + i)).Copy
Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Paste
Destination = Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Range("B1")
Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Range("B88:AC88").Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("C" & (38 + i) & "AD" & (38 + i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i

Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("A71:R71").Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Comparison").Range("A" & (1 + i) & "R" & (1 +  i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i

End Sub
```

Within each loop I'd like this block to loop 9 times

```
For i = 1 To 9

Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("B" & (38 + i)).Copy
Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Paste
Destination = Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Range("B1")
Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Range("B88:AC88").Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("C" & (38 + i) & "AD" & (38 + i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i
```

My guess is this is a fairly simple fix but I'm not sure and couldn't figure it out looking at other questions.

Comment: Just place the second loop inside the first loop and rename i of the the second loop to something else.

Answer (score 3):

At first glance the issue is that you can't use the counter "i" for both loops.  Change one of the counters to "j" and all references in the inner loop to "j" as well.  I'm not sure if there are other problems but that one jumps out at me.